# Insert transformation as new row rather than column

Tags: r, dplyr

Sample data:

```
Date <- as.Date(c('1-01-2008','2-01-2008', '3-01-2008', '1-01-2008','2-01-    2008', '3-01-2008','1-01-2008','2-01-2008', '3-01-2008', '1-01-2008','2-01-2008', '3-01-2008'), format = "%m-%d-%Y") 
Country <- c('US', 'US','US', 'JP', 'JP', 'JP', 'US', 'US','US', 'JP', 'JP', 'JP') 
Category <- c('Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'foo', 'foo','foo', 'foo','foo', 'foo') 
Value <- c(runif(12, -0.5, 10))
df <- data.frame(Date, Country, Category, Value)
```

What I want to do is subtract for each Month and within each country the values of Apple and foo (so for US and 2008-01-01 the value would be -1.2357797). However I want to *insert the result as a row*, with Category name e.g. "diff".

I figured out how to do this with dplyr/mutate but only by inserting a whole new *column*, in which case the table doesn't make sense anymore (as the categories don't fit and I am converting to list later on):

```
df <- df %>%
 group_by(Country, Date) %>%
    mutate(
      diff = Value[Category=="Apple"] - Value[Category=="foo"])
```

Edit: Important: I want to add multiple transformations in this way, not just the diff mentioned in the example.

Edit2: Thanks for all the helpful replies. Using the tidyr/dplyr method suggested by @akrun I will use this to insert more transformations:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
 df <- spread(df, Category, Value) %>%
    mutate(diff=Apple- foo, xyz = Apple+foo) %>% 
    gather(Category, Value, Apple:diff, Apple:xyz)
```

Comment: In your edit, instead of `gather(Category, Value, Apple:diff, Apple:xyz)` you should just use `gather(Category, Value, Apple:xyz)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can either use `data.table` or `dplyr`.  With `data.table`, convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by 'Date', 'Country', we get the difference of 'Value' for corresponding 'Apple' and 'foo' values in 'Category' column, and also create the 'Category' with 'diff' as value.  This will be a new summarised dataset ('dfN') which we can `rbind` with the original dataset using `rbindlist`.  If needed, we can `order` by 'Date', 'Country'

```
library(data.table)
dfN <- setDT(df)[, 
    list(Category="diff",
         Value=Value[Category=="Apple"]- Value[Category=="foo"]), 
               by = .(Date, Country)]
rbindlist(list(df, dfN))[order(Date,Country)]
#       Date Country Category      Value
# 1: 2008-01-01      JP    Apple  9.8861949
# 2: 2008-01-01      JP      foo  6.8009149
# 3: 2008-01-01      JP     diff  3.0852799
# 4: 2008-01-01      US    Apple -0.3047560
# 5: 2008-01-01      US      foo  9.1748432
# 6: 2008-01-01      US     diff -9.4795991
# 7: 2008-02-01      JP    Apple  8.7836616
# 8: 2008-02-01      JP      foo  5.4775849
# 9: 2008-02-01      JP     diff  3.3060767
#10: 2008-02-01      US    Apple  1.6155057
#11: 2008-02-01      US      foo  3.6720346
#12: 2008-02-01      US     diff -2.0565289
#13: 2008-03-01      JP    Apple  1.9879906
#14: 2008-03-01      JP      foo  7.1387297
#15: 2008-03-01      JP     diff -5.1507391
#16: 2008-03-01      US    Apple  1.1435151
#17: 2008-03-01      US      foo  0.6596238
#18: 2008-03-01      US     diff  0.4838913
```

---

Or another option is using `dcast/melt` from `data.table`

```
melt(dcast(setDT(df), Date+Country~Category, 
    value.var='Value')[, diff:= Apple-foo], 
      id.var=c('Date', 'Country'))
```

---

If we use the `gather/spread` option (similar to `melt/dcast`) from `tidyr`,

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
spread(df, Category, Value) %>%
       mutate(diff=Apple- foo) %>% 
       gather(Category, Value, Apple:diff)
```

Or use `dplyr`, we use the same technique, instead of `rbindlist`, we do with `bind_rows`.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>%
     group_by(Country, Date) %>%
     summarise(Value =  Value[Category=="Apple"] - 
                        Value[Category=="foo"],
                Category= "diff") %>%
     bind_rows(df, .) %>%
     arrange(Date, Country)
#        Date Country Category      Value
#       (date)  (fctr)    (chr)      (dbl)
#1  2008-01-01      JP    Apple  9.8861949
#2  2008-01-01      JP      foo  6.8009149
#3  2008-01-01      JP     diff  3.0852799
#4  2008-01-01      US    Apple -0.3047560
#5  2008-01-01      US      foo  9.1748432
#6  2008-01-01      US     diff -9.4795991
#7  2008-02-01      JP    Apple  8.7836616
#8  2008-02-01      JP      foo  5.4775849
#9  2008-02-01      JP     diff  3.3060767
#10 2008-02-01      US    Apple  1.6155057
#11 2008-02-01      US      foo  3.6720346
#12 2008-02-01      US     diff -2.0565289
#13 2008-03-01      JP    Apple  1.9879906
#14 2008-03-01      JP      foo  7.1387297
#15 2008-03-01      JP     diff -5.1507391
#16 2008-03-01      US    Apple  1.1435151
#17 2008-03-01      US      foo  0.6596238
#18 2008-03-01      US     diff  0.4838913
```

Comment: Thanks! your first method works fine, but the dplyr method gives me error:  *length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE*. One thing I should mention: I want to add several transformations in this way. I know vaguely that with dplyr I can just add more arguments, but with your data.table method I am a bit confused as to where to add the new arguments since they show up as separate columns in the dfN.

Comment: @Dreica Can you check the dplyr method now.  I updated the post.

Comment: @Dreica  After you create this column, you can do the further transformation.  Not sure how you wanted to do this unless a more concrete example is provided.  Regarding the scope of this question, this gives the expected answer.

Comment: @Dreica I also added 2 more options.  I guess that should solve the problem.

Comment: @Dreica Based on your example, I am not getting any error.  I use `dplyr_0.4.3`

Comment: Thanks, I will use the tidyr/dplyr method.

Comment: I like your last approach with spread/gather. (I think this should be at the top of your answer)

Comment: @docendodiscimus Shouldn't that be a little slower (when we reshape it from long to wide and then back)

Comment: We may have different views here but to me performance is not always the #1 concern. I think the spread/gather approach is very readable, easily understandable and therefore preferable to the other approaches, unless OP's data is so huge that it takes extremely long.

Comment: A last question: what is the meaning of the Apple:diff term in gather? Why do we choose Apple here? Sorry if it is a stupid question

Comment: @Dreica, please take a look at the documentation of `gather`. Type `help("gather")`. It's important that you understand the code you're using.. You can also run the code step-by-step (i.e. only first bit until before the `%>%` then first and second etc)